# Given component multidex.MultiDexApplication doesn't implement interface dagger.hilt.internal

Tags: android, xamarin, dagger, dagger-hilt, xamarin-binding

I'm creating Xamarin DLL from "Kotlin AAR" or "Kotlin Libraries".
AAR to DLL Converted Successfully.

There are **dagger** and **hilt** libraries in Kotlin AAR.
dagger-2.37.jar
hilt-core-2.37.jar
hilt-android-2.37.aar
dagger-lint-aar-2.37.aar

During Testing Xamarin App With Converted DLL;
Then throws an exception.

Exception Message
**Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager**

Please help to me.
[Windows - Visual Studio 2019 - Xamarin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9f5C.png)

Comment: Do you have an `Application` subclass?  Is it in your manifest?

Comment: Yes i have application subclass in manifest.xml

Comment: @Nitrodon Do you have any idea?